# Convert time (hh:mm) to (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss)

Tags: android, datetime

I have used time picker to select time.Now what i want is that i want to compare two time.
Code for time picker.

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
            TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {
        public int hour;
        public int min;
        public String time;

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

            hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            min = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, min, true);

        }

        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            time = String.valueOf(hourOfDay) + ":" + String.valueOf(minute);

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("TIME", time);

            getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), 1,
                    intent);
            getDialog().hide();

        }

        public String onTimeSelected() {
            return time;
        }

    }
```

Now in intent i am geting time in thuis format("22.00").To compare time i want time in this format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").
So how do i convert("22:00") to ("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")????

What i did

```
try {
                String time = data.getStringExtra("TIME");
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                Date timeCompare;
                timeCompare = sdf.parse(time);
                Date currentTime = new Date();
                int comareResult = timeCompare.compareTo(currentTime);

                if (comareResult == -1) {
                     time = new SimpleDateFormat(" HH:mm").format(date.getTime());
                    etStartTime.setText(time);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Your cannot select future time",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this code,

```
@Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            time = String.valueOf(hourOfDay) + ":" + String.valueOf(minute);

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("TIME", time);

            getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), 1,
                    intent);
            getDialog().hide();

        }
```

by

```
 @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
                date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                date.set(Calendar.AM_PM, date.get(Calendar.AM_PM));

                String time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(date.getTime());
             String time1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(date.getTime());

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("TIME", time);

            getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), 1,
                    intent);
            getDialog().hide();

        }
```

hope it will help you

Comment: Thankz it worked but sir while displaying the time in the edit text i want to only show the time like "12:12" but here i am getting like this Mon Nov 17 12:10:47 .....

Comment: just change String time = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(date.getTime()); like String time = new SimpleDateFormat(" HH:mm").format(date.getTime());

Comment: replace time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(date.getTime()); by time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(time);

Comment: I did what u said but now my app is crashing

Comment: remove time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(date.getTime()); and run again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65057/discussion-between-user3917131-and-moradiya-akash).

Answer (score 1):

Do like this,

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 
String time = String.valueof(sdf.format(c.getTime()));
```

You will get the time that you `selected` in your desired format.

Comment: But sir i am geting time like this(time = String.valueOf(hourOfDay) + ":" + String.valueOf(minute);)

Comment: You can create and pass Calendar instance in the intent as an extra. Use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String, java.io.Serializable) Calendar also has a compareto method http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#compareTo(java.util.Calendar)

Comment: doesnt matter. get it the way i said....the calender instance (c) in ur case already have the values of hourOfDay and minutes. so u dont need to do hourOfDay + minute and all kind of stuff

Comment: By your method i am getting the current time ,not the selected time

Comment: mine works perfectly... i dont y it didnt worked for u

Answer (score 0):

Try out as below:

```
private String getDate(String time) {    
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
       TimeZone tz = cal.getTimeZone();//get your local time zone.
       SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
       sdf.setTimeZone(tz);//set time zone.
       String localTime = sdf.format(new Date(time) * 1000));
       Date date = new Date();
       try {
            date = sdf.parse(localTime);//get local date
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      return date.toString();
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

From your code it appears, you are asking the user to input the time (only hours and minutes) and then passing the returned value in an intent as String. But you're expecting a complete date with year, month, day, hours,  minutes and seconds. For this you should ask the user to input both date and time using DatePicker and TimePicker respectively. Then using Hirak Chhatbar's code you can achieve the desired output format.